# Alt-X ignored on laptop keyboard in Windows 8.1, but normal with external keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I just got a new computer with Windows 8.1.  Whenever I need to type Alt-X or Alt-Shift-X in some applications, nothing happens.  It seems that it is intercepted, but nothing visible is triggered.  Other Alt combinations are fine.

I disabled the hotkeys from the graphics manager, but it did not help.  Does anyone have any idea what program could intercept Alt-X?  Or if there is some way in Windows to detect which program intercepts some keys?  Is there some page in the Control Panel for Windows shortcuts?

### Update

I need Alt-Shift-X for eclipse, and Alt-X for emacs on Cygwin (I tried disabling Cygwin).  Absolutely nothing happens when I hit Alt-X or Alt-Shift-X.

I tried [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/index.html) as suggested in the older post and it does give many hotkeys such as Alt-Tab, but nothing related to Alt-X.  (Warning about using Hotkey Commander: it seems to discover the active hotkeys by hitting all keys, so the Windows magnifier and narrator become active after you run it.)

## Update 2

I connected an external keyboard and Alt-X now works as expected with that keyboard.  I have not had other problems with the laptop keyboard except for Alt-X.  It is some type of "international" keyboard with a few weird symbols on some keys, but it is basically just a normal US keyboard.

I found the [driver page](http://support.toshiba.ca/support/isg/center/en/index.asp?s1=Notebook&s2=Satellite&s3=S50-B&s4=PSPQ6C-020001) for my laptop, but it does not seem to have a driver for the keyboard.  I have the latest bios.

I tried various keyboard layouts in the Control Panel, but it did not help.  The Device Manager lists my keyboard as Standard PS/2 Keyboard.

Comment: If this question is not appropriate for this stackexchange site, which site should I go to?

Comment: Which applications doe this not work in? Does anything happen instead?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you press Alt-X?